# Fetch particular sql row value using php

Tags: php, sql, echo, srv

```
Range | Count
-------------
PC       50
Printer  90
Intel    67
Others   78
```

Above this SQL query result values. I want to echo only Intel Range by using PHP code. Please help me.

Comment: Um... `SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE Range = 'Intel'` ?

Comment: *I want to echo only Intel Range by using PHP code* but you didn't tag `PHP` ;) Good luck expecting `SQL` guys to write `PHP` code ;)

Comment: Thanks ur comment bro. But My Question is, already run some queries and i get the result like this
Range | Count
-------------
PC       50
Printer  90
Intel    67
Others   78
In php code i want to echo onlly intel values

Comment: Still you can do this `SELECT * FROM (<<query>>) a WHERE Range = 'Intel'`